# Rails 3 acts_as_commentable Error: undefined local variable or method `acts_as_commentable'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-commentable

I'm building a Rails 3 app and am trying to install acts_as_commentable

Here's what I did:
Added to my Gemfile:

```
gem "acts_as_commentable"
```

Ran bundle install

Generated a Migration with the comments.rb (Comments table was created correctly)

I then wanted to enable my book controller for commenting, so I added to books_controller.rb

```
acts_as_commentable
```

But now I get an error when I load /books:

```
Routing Error

undefined local variable or method `acts_as_commentable' for BooksController:Class
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `act_as_commentable` is only define in Model. So you need define in your model, not your controller.

Comment: Woops! I should have had my cup of coffee this morning. Thank you! Do you know of any tutorials on how to actually implement commenting on a model/controller like Books. How to add it to the view's show page, add some ajax etc?

Comment: The usage in gem repository seems good : http://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable

Comment: The usage is at the model level, not the integration level. Does that make sense?